# How to grid updated and refresh data with KendoUI for Angular2?

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I am using the Kendo UI grid to edit records.

I have a load data function:

```
  private loadData(): void {
      this.gridView = {
          data: this.data.slice(this.skip, this.skip + this.pageSize),
          total: this.data.length
      };
  }
```

and I have a service that updates the data and stores it in `this.data content`:

```
this.dataservice.update().then(res => this.loadData());
```

However, the UI does not update. How should I update the grid UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the grid is not updated, I suppose that changes in the `loadData()` method are not detected.

A simple test in a plunker shows that such simplified approach works just fine:

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/TgvAEBiZxf5ntfUeIwJA?p=preview)

As a side note, if you are not seeing changes in the a specific row template, then this is a known issue logged here:

[Kendo Grid for Angular 2 Issue](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/82)

Comment: i use update the item like example：

`
export class AppComponent {
    public datas: any = [{ CategoryID: 1, CategoryName: "category 1" }];
    public view: any = {
      data: this.datas,
      total: 1
    }

    public update() {
      this.datas[0].CategoryName = 'category 1 updated.';
      this.view = {
        data: this.datas,
        total: 1
      }
    }
}
`

the grid are not detected, How to make it detect? thanks your answer.

Comment: sorry, I see the "Kendo Grid Angular 2 Issue" is similar,my currently resolve method, the updated object assign to a new object, new object replaces the address of the updated object.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest you follow the Github issue. Once it is resolved, a fix will be released and you will be able to test it right away

Comment: Yes, indeed. The demo was referencing Angular 2, which isn't supported anymore. I've updated the plunkr. It should work just fine now.